# Invalid parameter given. A valid $fileId[tmp_name] is expected

Tags: magento2, image-upload

I am trying to use an image uploader but it is generating error

> Invalid parameter given. A valid $fileId[tmp_name] is expected.

I debugged and find out that the problem is in image uploader class of magento core.
please check my code.
my code in `system.xml`

```
<field id="image_upload1" translate="label" type="image" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
      <label>Image Upload</label>
      <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
      <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">categoryBanner</upload_dir>
      <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">categoryBanner</base_url>
      <comment><![CDATA[Allowed file types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png, svg]]></comment> 
</field>
```

my code of `image.php`

```
namespace Afg\Customsettings\Model\Config\Backend;

class Image extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image
{
    /**
     * The tail part of directory path for uploading
     *
     */
    const UPLOAD_DIR = '/categoryBanner'; // Folder save image

    /**
     * Return path to directory for upload file
     *
     * @return string
     * @throw \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _getUploadDir()
    {
        return $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($this->_appendScopeInfo(self::UPLOAD_DIR));
    }

    /**
     * Makes a decision about whether to add info about the scope.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _addWhetherScopeInfo()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for allowed extensions of uploaded files.
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    protected function _getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'svg'];
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

**Issue:**
This seems to be a conflict between your selection of the tmp folder and the folders Magento considers secure for being used as tmp.

This can be observed in the `validateFieldId()` function in the class `Magento\Framework\File\Uploader`

```
[0] => string(15) "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP" <for windows and probably var/tmp for unix based systems>
[1] => string(30) "<magento_root>/pub/media"
[2] => string(24) "<magento_root>/var"
[3] => string(28) "<magento_root>/var/tmp"
[4] => string(37) "<magento_root>/pub/media/upload"
```

**Solution:**
Simply reconfigure your php.ini and set the value **upload_tmp_dir** to one of the allowed folders of Magento. Make sure you are updating the right version of php.ini

**Reference:**
I got the same issue and spent hours to get to the root of this and got it fixed by this small change.

**Request:**
upvote my response if it worked for you

Comment: I have a similar issue on 2.3.3, but unfortunately, edit value upload_tmp_dir did not help. $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] and sys_get_temp_dir() are different. Server Nexcess. Reson: "This actually makes sense, because /tmp is a symbolic link to /chroot/home/tmp on our servers."

Comment: There's also an open issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25835

Comment: works on me, Magento with MAMP 2.4

Comment: @RobOlmos link is the ultimate solver.
And specifically this could help - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25835#issuecomment-648109080

Answer (score 1):

Go to vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php

In function **_setUploadFileId($fileId)**, change:

```
$this->validateFileId($fileId);
```

to

> //$this->validateFileId($fileId);

this worked for me

Comment: by simply removing the validation, you don't solve the problem. You just ignore it. And: It's never a good idea to change a file in vendor/* as it will be rewritten on every deployment (composer install/update).

Comment: It's not a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Valid solution:**

- update php.ini variable "sys_temp_dir"

I was getting issue on bitnami AWS server.

**Edit:**
`/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini`

**Set:**
sys_temp_dir = "/opt/bitnami/php/tmp"

Restart apache server.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for Windows

---

Run the following command. You should get a path (I am using <YOUR_PATH_OUTPUT> as a placeholder). Copy that path.

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo sys_get_temp_dir() . PHP_EOL;
<YOUR_PATH_OUTPUT>
```

Now open your `php.ini` file and search for **sys_temp_dir** and paste the path here.

```
sys_temp_dir = '<YOUR_PATH_OUTPUT>'
```

Do not forget to **restart XAMPP** after this.

Answer (score -1):

For windows do 2 things

1. open php.ini file and set sys_temp_dir = "Your valid writable path"
2. Overwrite file Magento\Framework\File\Uploader and change in function validateFileId.

change
if (stripos($tmpName, $allowedFolder) === 0) {

to

if (stripos($tmpName, $allowedFolder) === false) {

Answer (score -2):

Go to vendor\magneto\framework\File\Uploader.php

In function _setUploadFileId($fileId), change:

`$this->validateFileId($fileId);`
To
`//$this->validateFileId($fileId);`